# contact form 7 send mail according to user response

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, contacts, contact-form-7

I have set up a Contact Form 7 on my website and It has a drop down so the user can select any option from the drop down . so my problem is this that when a user select from any of the 3 option , a mail has been sent to the user who has submitted a form but I want to sent the mail according to the desired option because I have three different mails for 3 different option 
So there is only one option for mailto . Is there any hook to send the  mail accoridng to user selection

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of what you want, but for what I understand you need to send the email to a different address according to the selected option in the dropdown, right?

The [pipes feature](http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/) allow that.

Your select tag would be something like that:

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                "Sales|sales@example.com"
                "Support|support@example.com"]
```

With that you'll have the following dropdown in your form:

[image: pipes example]

But in the email the `[your-recipient]` tag will produce the value after the "|" character. So you can put this tag inside the Mail fields (in your case, it should be in the "To" field, because you want to send the email to that address).

So, if for example an user select "CEO" in the dropdown, the email will be sent to `ceo@example.com`. And if another user select "Sales", then it will go to `sales@example.com`.